# Customization of View

Tags: custom-list

Please let me know how to customize the SharePoint view for discussion board like below ?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you can apply custom JavaScript into this view to modify the display dynamically.

To get the data of other columns using JavaScript, JavaScript Client Object Model would be a good option for you:

JavaScript Client Object Model

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185006(v=office.14).aspx

More information about JavaScript Client Object Model:

How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx

As an alternative, you can also use a Content Query Web Part with a custom item style to display the data you want there instead.

A demo about how to Configure a Custom Item Style for a Discussion Board using the Content Query Web Part:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/756834/Customizing-the-Content-Query-Web-Part-and-Item-St
https://www.xylos.com/en/corporate/blog/sharepoint-discussion-board-style-for-the-content-query-web-part
https://www.eliostruyf.com/discussion-board-style-for-the-content-query-web-part/
https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/custom-discussion-board-rollup-using-content-query-web-part-and-xsl/

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check and let you know.

Comment: @Tahir. The data which is showing above is after publishing from workflow it will show to all users. Which is the best way to implement.I dont think it will work in custom list because of discussion and reply.Kindly help me asap.

Comment: Is it possible to customize the Allitem.aspx for discussion board?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Please let me know how to do that?

Comment: You can use csom, css, html it's pure customization.

Comment: Customization ok but i just want to know how to edit the default  Allitem.aspx and make it to custom code.

Comment: As per your shared images above, this not out of the box, this is fully customizable